# Make customize save lists newline separated

Tags: customize

When saving changes using `customize` Emacs serializes lists space separated. This makes for example the `package-selected-packages` variable extremely long and hard to scan over.

Is it possible to make Emacs serialize lists more like it does with alists (like `package-archives` below)? That is, one element per line?

Basically, I want this:

```lisp
;;;; Custom mode ;;;;
(custom-set-variables
 …
 '(package-archives
   '(("gnu" . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")
     ("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/")
     ("melpa-stable" . "http://stable.melpa.org/packages/")))
 '(package-quickstart t)
 '(package-selected-packages '(ace-jump-mode add-node-modules-path  …  yaml-mode yatemplate))
 '(projectile-keymap-prefix "p")
 …
)
```

… to turn into this:

```lisp
;;;; Custom mode ;;;;
(custom-set-variables
 …
 '(package-archives
   '(("gnu" . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")
     ("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/")
     ("melpa-stable" . "http://stable.melpa.org/packages/")))
 '(package-quickstart t)
 '(package-selected-packages 
   '(ace-jump-mode
     add-node-modules-path
     …
     yaml-mode
     yatemplate))
 '(projectile-keymap-prefix "p")
 …
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function that does this serializing (printing to your `custom-file` or init file) is `custom-save-variables`.

You would need to redefine or advise that function, to have it use *pretty-printing* (functions from library `pp.el`, such as `pp-to-string` and `pp-display-expression`) instead of regular printing.

For example, `(pp-display-expression auto-mode-alist SOME-BUFFER)` pretty-prints the value of `auto-mode-alist`, inserting newlines etc.

---

(You might also want to file an enhancement request, to have Emacs do this by default. To do that, use `M-x report-emacs-bug`.)

Comment: I don't think `pp` inserts newlines when printing long lists

Comment: @rpluim: Yes, I didn't mean function `pp` itself but various functions in `pp.el`. I've replaced `pp.el` with "functions from library pp.el, such as pp-to-string and pp-display-expression". Function `pp` *does* include newlines, but you might not see them, depending on what you do with its return value.

Comment: `pp-display-expression` takes two arguments. Did you mean `pp-to-string`?

Comment: @rpluim: Yes, I added a `BUFFER` arg. And the answer already mentioned `pp-to-string` (as well as `pp-display-expression`). The point is to pretty-print, using functions from `pp.el`. There is more than one way to pretty-print a Lisp value.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I forgot about this question after writing it! :D
Thanks for the answer. It sounds like an interesting evening hack. I'll see if I can put something together at some point.